# Second Order Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The two equations I need to solve are as follows: $$ y'' - 4y = cos(2x) $$ $$ y''-4y=xe^x $$

I am not sure how to go about solving these. However, I know how to, and, have already solved this equation: $$ y'' - 4y = 0 $$ which gives me the solution $$y=c_1 e^{2x} + c_2 e^{-2x}$$

What are the differences in solving these different types of equations? Thanks

Comment: One can use the [Method of undetermined coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_undetermined_coefficients) or alternatively, you can use [Variation of Parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters) if you want to avoid guessing the form of the particular solution.

Comment: Are you familiar with Laplace Transform ?

Answer (score 2):

As projectilemotion commented, you can either use the method of undetermined coefficients, or you can use variation of parameters. Dr. Graubner has provided you a solution with the method of undetermined coefficients, which does require a little bit of guessing. This is why I prefer variation of parameters, which I will provide in my answer

Given a non-homogeneous ODE of the form $y''+q(x)y'+r(x)y=g(x)$, first solve the homogeneous ODE $y''+q(x)y'+r(x)y=0$.

Let your solutions to the  homogeneous ODE be $y_1$ and $y_2$ (in your case $e^{2x}$ and $e^{-2x}$).

Recall that the Wronskian is given by $$W(y_1(x),y_2(x))=y_1(x)(y_2(x))'-y_2(x)(y_1(x))'$$

Using the method of variation of parameters, our solution for the non-homogeneous ODE is $$y(x)=-y_1(x)\int\frac{y_2(x)g(x)}{W(y_1(x),y_2(x))}dx+y_2(x)\int\frac{y_1(x)g(x)}{W(y_1(x),y_2(x))}dx$$.

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

HINT: for the first equation make for the partial equation the Ansatz $$y_P=A\sin(2x)+B\cos(2x)$$
and for the second one $$y_P=e^x(Ax+B)$$